# VRX with ignition gazebo fortress

Tags: gazebo-ignition, gazebo-plugins, ignition-fortress, gz-sim

I am working on my master thesis project which involves water/waves and a surface vehicle with ros2. I came across https://github.com/osrf/vrx github repo, but the repo is for gazebo garden and further and i have to work with ignition version(ign-fortress). can anyone help me in this regards?
my attempts: I have used jessica/ignition_wildlife branch form vrx, but colcon build  throws following error.

```
In file included from /usr/include/ignition/plugin1/gz/plugin/Register.hh:22,
                 from /home/hem/test_ws/src/vts_custom/src/Surface.cc:24:
/usr/include/ignition/plugin1/gz/plugin/detail/Register.hh:28:10: fatal error: gz/utilities/SuppressWarning.hh: No such file or directory
   28 | #include <gz/utilities/SuppressWarning.hh>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! This may help: [1](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/issues/20923)

Comment: thank you. the problem has been resolved with the given library installation.